# Свой адаптер для listview

Tags: java, android

Сделал свой адаптер для listview из примера, но возник такой вопрос список состоит из 6 элементов, на в каждом из элементов фиксированный набор ресурсов в соответствии с классом DataAdapter, в первом допустим должно быть 6 ресурсов во втором 5 а в третьем уже 4, можно ли как-нибудь отменить эту фиксацию?

Вместо не достающих ресурсов я добавлял пустые строки.

```
list.add(new DataAdapter(R.string.N5A, R.string.Pr1, R.string.N2,  R.string.Nm,R.drawable.foot,R.drawable.bus));
list.add(new DataAdapter(R.string.N14,R.string.p,R.string.p,    R.string.Nm1,R.drawable.c,R.drawable.c));
list.add(new DataAdapter(R.string.N1,R.string.Pr1, R.string.N2,R.string.Nm2,R.drawable.foot, R.drawable.bus));
list.add(new DataAdapter(R.string.N11,R.string.p, R.string.p,   R.string.Nm3,R.drawable.c, R.drawable.c));
list.add(new DataAdapter(R.string.N1B,R.string.Pr1, R.string.p,   R.string.Nm4, R.drawable.foot,R.drawable.bus));
list.add(new DataAdapter(R.string.N16A, R.string.Pr1, R.string.N2,  R.string.Nm5, R.drawable.foot, R.drawable.bus));
```

Код DataAdapter

```
public class DataAdapter {


    private int flagID;
    public int imgID;
    private int nameID;
    private int nameID2;
    private int nameID3;

    private int abbreviationID;

    public DataAdapter(int _nameID,int _nameID3,  int _nameID2, int _abbreviationID,int _imgID, int _flagID){
        nameID = _nameID;
        nameID3 = _nameID3;
        nameID2 = _nameID2;
        abbreviationID = _abbreviationID;
        imgID = _imgID;
        flagID = _flagID;
    }

    public int getNameID3(){
        return nameID3;
    }
    public int getNameID(){
        return nameID;
    }

    public int getNameID2(){
        return nameID2;
    }

    public int getAbbreviationID() {
        return abbreviationID;
    }
    public int getFlagID(){
        return flagID;
    }
    public int getImgID(){
        return imgID;
    }

}
```

Класс MyListAdapter если нужно

```
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    /*
    * Создаем объекты для отображения внешнего вида элемента
    * и объекта списка, с которым будет производиться работа
    */
    private LayoutInflater LInflater;
    private ArrayList<DataAdapter> ls;
    /*
     * Конструктор класса. В данном случае лишь транслируется лист с данными
     * в лист адаптера, с которым будет производиться непосредственная работа
     */
    public MyListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DataAdapter> data){
        ls = data;
        LInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    /*
     * Далее идут стандартные методы родительского класса BaseAdapter.
     * Внимательно ознакомьтесь с отличиями методов в уроке и методов,
     * которые автоматически создает Android Studio.
     * Данные методы должны работать непосредственно с используемым нами ArrayList
     * и структурой данных, формируемой классом Dataadapter
     */

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ls.size();
    }

    @Override
    public DataAdapter getItem(int position) {
        return ls.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /*
     * Метод, в котором формируется внешний вид элементов с его наполнением
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        View v = convertView;

        /*
         * В том случае, если вид элемента не создан, производится его создание
         * с помощью ViewHolder и тегирование данного элемента конкретным holder объектом
         */
        if ( v == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            v = LInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_test, parent, false);
            holder.im = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            holder.img1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img1);
            holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.m1);
            holder.name3 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.m2));
            holder.name2 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.m3));
            holder.name4 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2));
            v.setTag(holder);
        }

        /*
         * После того, как все элементы определены, производится соотнесение
         * внешнего вида, данных и конкретной позиции в ListView.
         * После чего из ArrayList забираются данные для элемента ListView и
         * передаются во внешний вид элемента
         */
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        DataAdapter dataAdapter = getData(position);

        holder.im.setImageResource(dataAdapter.getFlagID());
        holder.img1.setImageResource(dataAdapter.getImgID());
        holder.name.setText(v.getResources().getString(dataAdapter.getNameID()));
        holder.name3.setText(v.getResources().getString(dataAdapter.getAbbreviationID()));
        holder.name4.setText(v.getResources().getString(dataAdapter.getNameID3()));
        holder.name2.setText(v.getResources().getString(dataAdapter.getNameID2()));
        return v;
    }

    /*
     * Метод, который забирает объект из ArrayList для дальнейшей работы с ним
     * и передачи его данных в элемент ListView
     */
    DataAdapter getData(int position){
        return (getItem(position));
    }

    /*
     * Данная структура данных необходима для того, чтобы при пролистывании
     * большого списка не возникало артефактов и перескакивания данных с одной позиции ListView
     * на другую, что достигается тегированием каждого элемента ListView
     */
    private static class ViewHolder {
        private ImageView im,img1;
        private TextView name, name2,name3,name4;

    }
}
```

Comment: Не в тему, но советую именовать переменные и другие сущности осмысленно, ибо в том, что есть, можно легко запутаться. Класс `DataAdapter` вроде как должен быть адаптером, однако это просто данные из модели.

Comment: А по теме: можно создать некоторый базовый класс, в котором будет три ресурса и отнаследовать от него другие классы с бОльшим количеством ресурсов. Или же хранить ресурсы в классе в некоторой коллекции. По-разному можно сделать.

Comment: Сложна сложна...

Comment: Сколько Вы программируете вообще и сколько на Java?

Comment: Непонятно, что вы хотите отменить. Чтобы при инициализации ```new DataAdapter()``` указывать только необходимое количество параметров? Или чтобы в ячейках ```ListView``` не отображались элементы, которых нет в ```DataAdapter```?

Comment: @post_zeew программирую около 3 лет в основном были паскаль и си++ на java недавно перешел может месяца 3 назад.

Comment: @eugeneek скорее 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну как Вам сказать, попробуйте к примеру использовать "перегрузку конструкторов"

```
public DataAdapter(int _nameID,int _nameID3,  int _nameID2, int _abbreviationID,int _imgID, int _flagID){
        nameID = _nameID;
        nameID3 = _nameID3;
        nameID2 = _nameID2;
        abbreviationID = _abbreviationID;
        imgID = _imgID;
        flagID = _flagID;
    }

public DataAdapter(int _nameID,int _nameID3,  int _nameID2){
        nameID = _nameID;
        nameID3 = _nameID3;
        nameID2 = _nameID2;

    }
```

Еще можно использовать переменно количество элементов - но есть недостаток - нужно строго соблюдать позицию и делать проверку на их наличие.

```
public DataAdapter(int... ids){
        nameID = ids[0];
        nameID2 = ids[1];
        nameID3 = ids[2];
        abbreviationID = ids[3];
        imgID = ids[4];
        flagID = ids[5];
    }
```

А еще можно сделать пустой конструктор, инициализировать Ваш объект

и через set указывать только нужные параметры

```
DataAdapter data = new DataAdapter();
data.setflagID(flagId);
```

Я привел только три, есть еще не менее 2х вариантов. Но думаю вам и этого будет достаточно. У каждого способа есть удобства и свои недостатки, что подойдет вам в данном месте, решать только Вам